# how to iterate through a folder writing each folder name into a string array

Tags: c#

I am trying iterate through a folder structure writing each folder name inside folder A to a string array.

IE:

```
Folder A
    -Folder A1
    -Folder A2
    -Folder A3
    -Folder A4
    -Folder A5
    -Folder A6
```

and then each file name inside each of the subfolders to a separate string array

I would like to be able to do this in C#. Can someone help me with this issue as I'm not sure where to start on this issue.

Comment: Remember when asking questions showing a starting point of code you've tried goes a long way.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way you can do it. You can probably still refactor this

```
        var path = @"C:\\Katas"; 

        var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);  //Your string array of folders

        var files = new List<string>();

        foreach (String s in folders)
        {
            var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(s).ToList();

            files.AddRange(fileList);

        }

        files.ToArray();   //Your string array of files
```

Comment: Although all the other answers were very good, this is the one that helped me the most and was closest to my requirements. Needless to say the other answers were very good. Many thanks for all of your assistance in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You already have that: `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` gives you all that, and more. But, here you go, a wrapper:

```
class DirectoryInfoWrapper
{
  private DirectoryInfo BackingStore { get ; set ; }

  public DirectoryInfoWrapper( DirectoryInfo dir )
  {
    this.BackingStore = dir ;
    return ;
  }

  public DirectoryInfoWrapper Parent
  {
    get
    {
      DirectoryInfo parent = this.BackingStore.Parent ;
      return parent != null ? new DirectoryInfoWrapper(parent) : null ;
    }
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get
    {
      return this.BackingStore.Name ;
    }
  }

  public DirectoryInfoWrapper[] Subdirectories
  {
    get
    {
      return this
             .BackingStore
             .EnumerateDirectories()
             .Select( x => new DirectoryInfoWrapper(x) )
             .ToArray()
             ;
    }
  }

  public string[] Files
  {
    get
    {
      return this
             .BackingStore
             .EnumerateFiles()
             .Select( x => x.Name )
             .ToArray()
             ;
    }
  }

}
```